# How to verify extension method via Moq

Tags: asp.net-core, mocking, moq, xunit

In the Configure method I'm calling my extension method

```
app.UseJsonResponse();
```

My extension method

```
public static class JsonResponseExtension
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseJsonResponse(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<JsonResponseMiddleware>();
        return app;
    }
}
```

I want to test **UseJsonResponse** method. I wrote

```
public class JsonResponseExtensionTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void UseJsonResponse()
    {
        var iApplicationBuilderMock = new Mock<IApplicationBuilder>();
        iApplicationBuilderMock
            .Verify(b => b.UseMiddleware<JsonResponseMiddleware>(), Times.Never);

    }
}
```

And i'm getting an exception

```
Extension methods (here: UseMiddlewareExtensions.UseMiddleware) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
```

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

`UseMiddleware` is an extension which can't be mocked, you've got to mock what the extension invokes on the interface. In this case the method is probably

```
IApplicationBuilder Use(Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate> middleware);
```

[Source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/IApplicationBuilder.cs)

I would need to know more about `JsonResponseMiddleware` as the `UseMiddleware` extension, and the extensions that it too invokes, has quite a bit going on, some of it to do with the interfaces `JsonResponseMiddleware` implements. For reference, the `UseMiddleware` extensions can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Extensions/UseMiddlewareExtensions.cs).

With the information at hand, after invoking your `UseJsonResponse` extension the following will verify that `Use` was invoked once.

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    var applicationBuilderMock = new Mock<IApplicationBuilder>();
    var mockedApplicationBuilder = applicationBuilderMock.Object;

    mockedApplicationBuilder.UseJsonResponse();

    applicationBuilderMock.Verify(x => x.Use(It.IsAny<Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate>>()), Times.Once);
}
```

To take it further I would need to know more about `JsonResponseMiddleware` as mentioned. It also looks like a lot more effort to include a check for the `JsonResponseMiddleware` type.